# rails cancan sunspot search not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, cancan, sunspot

I am using `'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.0.0'` and `'cancan', '~> 1.6.8'` gems in my rails app but I can't do a  successful search using those two, say I have a resource called `Photos` and this is my search query

```
photos = Photos.accessible_by(current_ability).search do
 fulltext params[:query]
end.results
```

but the search happens on all photos not on those that belongs to current user, I believe `current_user.photos` and `Photos.accessible_by(current_ability)` are the same.

My ability.rb has this permissions

```
can :list, Photos
can [:read, :create, :update, :destroy], Photos, user_id: user.id
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: not giving any answer right away. Just a suggestion I thought I would give here. Please use `gem cancancan` instead of `gem cancan`. Gem cancan is no longer maintained, but someone updated it to cancancan.

Comment: ok will try with `cancancan` gem but do you think that'll fix the issue ?

Comment: I agree with @Rubyrider on moving to cancancan + make sure the ability `can :list, Photos` not casuing the issue! ... not sure what `list` action is!

Comment: no help, got the same behaviour with the new gem also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the Sunspot `search` will filter based on a given scope, it just takes a model argument so it will search across all instances.

You could do the search first and then filter the results but that would mess up paging if you are using Sunspot to do that.

A better solution might be to index the `user_id` attribute in Solr so that you can do a search filtered by that as well as by the free text input. It isn't ideal because you would be duplicating authorisation logic.

So in your model you would need:

```
searchable do
  ...
  integer :user_id
end
```

You would need to rebuild the search index.

And then include it in your search filter with something like:

```
photos = Photos.search do
  fulltext params[:query]
  with(:user_id).equal_to(current_ability.user.id)
end.results
```

There is a discussion of a similar problem [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-sunspot/d-xMj0BG7xE).

Comment: ya I found out later that it is not that easy or not supported by sunspot search so I did the search on whole collection and then later filtered the search result against the user's records, thanks though, will try adding user id in the index

Comment: I had to use string instead of integer to index my user id and current_ability.user was a private method but I used current_user.id and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even if I consider Steve answer correct you will have two different places in which you define permissions for the photos, and this is not nice because we are actually using cancan for that.

I would prefer using something like:

```
photos = Photo.search do
 fulltext params[:query]
 with(:id, Photo.accessible_by(current_ability).pluck(:id))
end.results
```

so you do not have to duplicate the logic for permissions.

btw: why `Photos` instead of `Photo`?